# Combine SwitchNavigator and DrawerNavigator in react native

Tags: react-native

please help, i'm having code for createAppContainer like :

```
const App = createAppContainer(

  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      Auth: AuthStack,
      Dashboard: DashboardStack,
      Draw:DrawerNavigator
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
    }
  )
);
```

and the button code for it:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={ () =>this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}>
     <View >
     <Image source={iconSetting}/>
     </View></TouchableHighlight>
```

and the drawerNavigator is:

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home:HomeScreen,
    Map:Map,
    Setting:Setting,
  },
```

but the result is error : TypeError: ._this2.props.navigation.openDrawer is not a function

====================================

edit: i fixed it by created a new screen, from auth screen then go to new screen so the drawerNavigator works normally.

Comment: Is your TouchableHighlight in your Home/Map or Setting screen?

Comment: @kenodek in HomeScreen

Comment: @walidthalib do you have a working example, maybe that you can share? Thanks